# Dice Sorensen Distance error calculating Bigrams without using Intersect method

Tags: c#, .net, string, distance, intersection

I have been programming an object to calculate the DiceSorensen Distance between two strings. The logic of the operation is not so difficult. You calculate how many two letter pairs exist in a string, compare it with a second string and then perform this equation
2(x intersect y)/ (|x| . |y|)

where |x| and |y| is the number of bigram elements in x & y. Reference can be found here for further clarity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient

So I have tried looking up how to do the code online in various spots but every method I have come across uses the 'Intersect' method between two lists and as far as I am aware this won't work because if you have a string where the bigram already exists it won't add another one. For example if I had a string 
'aaaa'
I would like there to be 3 'aa' bigrams but the Intersect method will only produce one, if i am incorrect on this assumption please tell me cause i wondered why so many people used the intersect method. My assumption is based on the MSDN website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.90).aspx

So here is the code I have made

```
public static double SorensenDiceDistance(this string source, string target)
{
    // formula 2|X intersection Y|
    //         --------------------
    //          |X|     +     |Y|

    //create variables needed
    List<string> bigrams_source = new List<string>();
    List<string> bigrams_target = new List<string>();

    int source_length;
    int target_length;
    double intersect_count = 0;
    double result = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: string length source is " + source.Length);

    //base case
    if (source.Length == 0 || target.Length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //extract bigrams from string 1
    bigrams_source = source.ListBiGrams();
    //extract bigrams from string 2
    bigrams_target = target.ListBiGrams();

    source_length = bigrams_source.Count();
    target_length = bigrams_target.Count();
    Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: bigram counts are source: " + source_length + " . target length : " + target_length);
    //now we have two sets of bigrams compare them in a non distinct loop

    for (int i = 0; i < bigrams_source.Count(); i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bigrams_target.Count(); y++)
        {
            if (bigrams_source.ElementAt(i) == bigrams_target.ElementAt(y))
            {
                intersect_count++;
                //Console.WriteLine("intersect count is :" + intersect_count);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("intersect line value : " + intersect_count);

    result = (2 * intersect_count) / (source_length + target_length);

    if (result < 0)
    {
        result = Math.Abs(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In the code somewhere you can see I call a method called listBiGrams and this is how it looks

```
public static List<string> ListBiGrams(this string source)
{
    return ListNGrams(source, 2);
}

public static List<string> ListTriGrams(this string source)
{
    return ListNGrams(source, 3);
}

public static List<string> ListNGrams(this string source, int n)
{
    List<string> nGrams = new List<string>();

    if (n > source.Length)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (n == source.Length)
    {
        nGrams.Add(source);
        return nGrams;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length - n; i++)
        {
            nGrams.Add(source.Substring(i, n));
        }

        return nGrams;
    }
}
```

So my understanding of the code step by step is 
1) pass in strings
2) 0 length check
3) create list and pass up bigrams into them
4) get the lengths of each bigram list
5) nested loop to check in source position[i] against every bigram in target string and then increment i until no more source list to check against
6) perform equation mentioned above taken from wikipedia
7) if result is negative Math.Abs it to return a positive result (however i know the result should be between 0 and 1 already this is what keyed me into knowing i was doing something wrong)

the source string i used is source = "this is not a correct string" and the target string was, target = "this is a correct string"

the result I got was -0.090909090908

I'm SURE (99%) that what I'm missing is something small like a mis-calculated length somewhere or a count mis-count. If anyone could point out what i'm doing wrong I'd be really grateful. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, yet this similarity metric on strings is new to me so I took a look.

[Algorith implementation in various languages](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Dice's_coefficient)

As you may notice the C# version uses [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and takes advantage of the [IntersectWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx) method.

> A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.

This solves your string 'aaaa' puzzle. Only one bigram there.

[My naive implementation on Rextester](http://rextester.com/GRLJ74051)

If you prefer Linq then I'd suggest `Enumerable.Distinct`, `Enumerable.Union` and `Enumerable.Intersect`. These should mimic very well the duplicate removal capabilities of the `HashSet`.

Also found this nice [StringMetric framework](https://github.com/rockymadden/stringmetric/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/rockymadden/stringmetric/similarity/DiceSorensenMetric.scala) written in Scala.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank you for doing this but the Intersect method is exactly what I want to avoid. The Intersect method only added one bigram 'aa' from your string that you tested but in the environment I need to produce every Bigram that occurs in the string even if it has occurred already. So the string 'aaaa' would produce the set of bigram strings [aa], [aa], [aa]. Also no it isn't homework.